# Delete on windows vista and seven -- discovery process

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-explorer, time

I've recently encountered a problem. Using `svn` at work I needed to clear some space.
As you may know `svn` directories are full of sub-directories and files.

So the delete process begins with a step of discovering the items to be deleted (I guess this is for displaying the progress bar).
But in my case it ended up to be still running after I watched `Braveheart` (Off-topic: good film in my opinion. On-topic: and it last 2h50) and counting 440 000+ files.

I finally decided to cut off the process and use the good old `cmd` with a `del <directory>` to do the job. (Done in some minutes)

So I'm wondering if someone know how to override the system to make it actually begins the process while scanning the other items? At the end, I just want the file to be deleted and I don't care the number of files to be deleted. On the contrary I care about the time it takes.

Thanks

#### EDIT 1 :

It seems that the problem may have something to do with Indexing and windows search.

I found someone talking about unchecking the "index this folder" [here](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/disable-indexing-in-windows-7-to-speed-up-deletion-of-many-files/) and also two articles on how to disable the windows search to solve [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/73204/correct-way-to-disable-indexing-in-windows-7) and [other](http://windows7themes.net/disable-windows-7-indexing.html)

But no official explanations.

#### EDIT 2 :

Tested the deactivation of windows search service. Lowers the time of discovery, but don't disable it.