# Remove any Windows 7 indexing cache

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, cache

I've disabled the file indexing service in Windows 7 (as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/338155/96867)) which worked like a charm.

My questions are:

1. Does disabling the service also remove any existing cache? The answer linked to above suggests that it doesn't.
2. If it doesn't how could I safely remove it myself?

Windows is installed on a not terribly large SSD so:

- I don't really need an index and
- I would like to reclaim as much space as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall it completely through "Programs and settings" -> "Turn windows features on or off" (?correct me someone if I'm wrong). The other answer for the same question lists this way.

This has nothing to do with SSD as this is just another way of accessing data, after isbaling index there would be no search fields in Start menu or Explorer windows. However minimizing disk writes will give your SSD a life boost.

Comment: I don't want to remove search functionality completely. I just want to prevent indexing and remove all traces of an index.

Comment: That's fun, but you can't remove search functionality from Windows. You just can enable or disable it. I still wonder would disabling be sufficient to clear indexes.